# How add image to site on Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to add one picture to the article. How to do it? Code under.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code which shows how to add  images to database using a form, read it back and display it on a web page in the below link:

https://github.com/csev/dj4e-samples/tree/master/pics

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an Image field to your Django model.
[Django Image Field Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
```

Note that you should also provide media settings in order to save those images.
[Media Root Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT)

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Access your images in the template later like so:

```
<img src="{{ [object_name].[image_field_name].url }}">
```